# connecting two objects to each other

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got these four classes. 
What I'm trying to do is to add a "Liftcard" to a "User" by using the customerID. this is what I got so far, but it don't seem to work. Im pretty sure the problem is in the public void regLiftCard() method in the window class. Anyone got any idea what i should do?
(Im using arraylist)

User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
private String surename, firstName, gender, age;
private int customerID;
public LiftCard liftCard;
User next;
```

Same class:

```
    public LiftCard getLiftCard(){
    return liftCard;
}

public void setLiftCard(LiftCard liftC){
    liftCard = liftC;
}
```

Window class:

```
      public void regLiftCard() 
  {
        int cardtype = Integer.parseInt(cardTypeField.getText());
        int customerID = Integer.parseInt(findCustomerField.getText());

        if(cardtype == 1 || cardtype == 2 || cardtype == 3 || customerID != 0) 
      {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Du må fylle inn hvilket kort du skal ha 1/2/3");

      try
      {
          User uu = userA.findById(customerID);
            if (uu != null) {
                if (uu.getLiftCard() != null) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Kunden har allerede kort");
                }

            }
            String fornavn = firstNameField.getText();
            String etternavn = surenameField.getText();
            String alder = ageField.getText();
            String kjonn = genderField.getText();
            LiftCard c = new LiftCard(cardNumber, cardtype);
            if (userA.findByCardNumber(cardNumber) == null) {
                uu.setLiftCard(c);
            } else {
                uu = new User(customerID, fornavn, etternavn, alder, kjonn);
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nytt kort/kunde er registrert");

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Feil i nummerformat!");
        }
      }
    }
```

UserArchive class:

```
    public void regLiftCard(User u) {
    list.add(u);
}
```

Liftcard class:

```
private int cardNumber, cardType;

public LiftCard(int cN, int cT)
{
    cardNumber = cN;
    cardType = cT;
}

public int getCardNumber(){
    return cardNumber;
}

public int getcardType(){
    return cardType;
}

public String toString()
{
    return cardNumber + "\t" + cardType;
}
```

}

Comment: Define "doesn't work". So far it's just a code dump with zero explanation of expected or actual behavior. Unrelated, but consider being consistent with your formatting, brace placement, etc.

Comment: Consider making the `liftCard` field `private` and `final` and set it in the constructor of the `User` class.

Comment: Sorry, I'm really new at this. What i want this to do when i call the regLiftCard is to assign the new card to a user. so if i print my customerlist it will say something like this: customerID has LiftcardID. I suck at explaining, sorry.

Comment: @TheCat If i do that, wont I always have to register a card when Im adding a new user?

Comment: Well it depends if you know what card as user can at the time you create the `User`s. You can always give a `User` a `null` card.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're trying to register a card to a unique User, so on regListCard:

You're looking for a user.
If the user is not null, you look for it's card.
If the card it's not null you're saying that this user already has a card.
Then, you get all the attributes input about the user and the card.
Then, you create a card.
Then, searchs for a user with this card and you set the card you created before to this user.
BUT, there's a possibility that the user you're assigning this card maybe null, because you're looking for a user by it's card, and if it's null, you assign this card to him which is not possible if he is null, and seems that here is the problem.
Then, if there are no user with this card, you are instantiating a new User, but not assigning any card.

So, put this:

```
else {
            uu = new User(customerID, fornavn, etternavn, alder, kjonn);
            uu.setLiftCard(c); 
        }
```

after this:

```
if (uu != null) {
            if (uu.getLiftCard() != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Kunden har allerede kort");
            }
```

and get the inputs before the "if". Try it and tell us how it worked, and sorry if I do not understood your code.

Comment: I think you got my problem pretty much right on the spot. So i tried what you said, but the users card number is still null.

Comment: Oh, I can't see where you're initializing cardNumber, is it a Window class field? Check if you're giving it a value that's not 0 or else. Anyways, I forgot to tell you that when you create the new User, you have to set the card also, so the resulting code will be:

    else {
        uu = new User(customerID, fornavn, etternavn, alder, kjonn);
        uu.setLiftCard(c);
    }

Comment: Im really grateful for your help, something worked, I got this far: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nytt kort/kunde er registrert"); But there still no card on the user(cardNumber is still null, and cardType is blank). It probably got something to do with my setLiftCard() method, or I'm doing some other things completely wrong, which is just as likely. stupid question, but got any other inputs? And yeah, the cardNumber is set to 0.

Comment: No, setLiftCard() seems OK. Have you initializated the card before running setLiftCard(c)?

Comment: hmm. In the User class i have public LiftCard liftCard; and in the constructor I have liftCard = null;

Comment: User next;

Why you have a reference of User on your User class?
Are you setting the card, the name, etc to this user?

Please, post the Constructor of the User class.

Also, make the the liftCard atribute private, and use this.liftCard = liftC to set the value.